# Slack bot/Gmail workspace

Tags: slack, messaging, google-workspace, privacy

Is there any functionality or bot that can send messages directly to a user on Slack that then deletes it after some time once the user reads it? I want to send private messages within my company and avoid using any 3rd party software. We're also using Google Workspace, in case it has this ability.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per Slack documentation, https://api.slack.com/bot-users#methods you can create a bot to send messages but not for deleting messages

In Google Workspace you can create bots and you can delete messages, but it has to be done in a public space, not in a private message https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/delete